# How to replace the special characters from input string in map reduce program

Tags: java, mapreduce

I am able replace the special characters in normal java program.

This is my java code:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "This785($^#')\"";
    System.out.println(s);
    s=s.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]", "");
    System.out.println(s);

}
```

But I am trying same in my map reduce program but this is not working

```
 public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {

        String s = value.toString().replaceAll("\\w+\\s+","");
        String[] words=s.split(" ");
        for(String a:words){


output.collect(new Text(a),new  IntWritable(1));
        }
    }
```

sample Input for map reduce program

```
   "This@#$ is$# word$%^ (Count)"
  "This@#$ is$# word$%^ (Count)"
```

output of map reduce program

```
 "This@#$   2
  (Count)"  2
    is$#    2
 word$%^    2
```

Am I doing something wrong please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You regex has changed from `[^\\w\\s]` to `\\w+\\s+`

This regex means, match for one or more alphabet (a-z/A-Z) or number (alpha numberic) followed by a space or tab or new line etc. and replace it with empty string. In your string you have:

```
 "This@#$ is$# word$%^ (Count)"
```

You dont satisfy the case and hence the output.You either have $ or # or ^ followed by a space but not alpha numeric character followed by a space.